# How to move line?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, core-graphics

How to move horizontal line in a vertical direction?
I can draw a straight horizontal line and I need to move it using long press.
How can I do that?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    if let touch = touches.first 
    {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
        DrawLine(FromPoint: currentPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)
    }
}
func DrawLine(FromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let lineWidth : CGFloat = 5
    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: FromPoint.x, y: FromPoint.y))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: FromPoint.x + 200, y: FromPoint.y))
    context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor)
    context?.strokePath()
    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can draw a horizontal line using UIView and can move it in vertical direction using *UIView.animate* method by providing the required options.

In your ViewController define the following variables:

```
var scanlineRect = CGRect.zero
var scanlineStartY: CGFloat = 0
var scanlineStopY: CGFloat = 0
var topBottomMargin: CGFloat = 30
var scanLine: UIView = UIView()
```

Call *drawLine* method inside *viewDidLoad* method and call *moveVertically* method on your touch event:

```
func drawLine() {
        self.addSubview(scanLine)
        scanLine.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.8, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1.0) // green color
        scanlineRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: 2)
        scanlineStartY = topBottomMargin
        scanlineStopY = self.frame.size.height - topBottomMargin
    }

func moveVertically() {
        scanLine.frame  = scanlineRect
        scanLine.center = CGPoint(x: scanLine.center.x, y: scanlineStartY)
        scanLine.isHidden = false
        weak var weakSelf = scanLine
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: {() -> Void in
            weakSelf!.center = CGPoint(x: weakSelf!.center.x, y: scanlineStopY)
            }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: And what if I have 3 lines? How can i distinguish them and move the needed one?

Comment: You can draw three lines by passing the frame CGRect to the method and call the moveVertically method for the line instance that you want to move. So you can modify above code as per your requirement.

Comment: The above code is to draw a line and move it in vertical  direction.

Comment: What does CGRect frame mean? I don't know how to use it.

Comment: You are creating line using UIView, so you need to define the view's frame using CGRect structure that contains the location and dimension of view (eg. Line)

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to draw this line on a UIView, and move the UIView upwards or to any position you want like so:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                yourView.origin = CGPoint(yourView.frame.origin.x, yourYPosition)

            }, completion: { (value: Bool) in
                //do anything after animation is done
            })
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that using UIImageView?

Comment: yes of course ,just replace the UIView with UIImageView